# Power Query Add Column with Sorted Text for each cell

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Given the following M code:

```
let Customer_Names = Table.FromRecords(
{  
    [Customer_Name = "Roger Kevan"],
    [Customer_Name = "Quincy Tod"],
    [Customer_Name = "Legend Vere"],
    [Customer_Name = "Hendrix Triston"],
    [Customer_Name = "Brycen Hallam"]
})
 

in  
    Customer_Names
```

Which yields a table with a few random names as in the image:

[image]

Could you please show me how to add a new column with the sorted name?

for example in the first cell in the Customer_Name column, for the name "Roger Kevan" - the resulting text in the new column should be: "aeegnorrrv"

My purpose is to detect names that contain misspellings or same names with different order of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
let Customer_Names = Table.FromRecords(
{  
    [Customer_Name = "Roger Kevan"],
    [Customer_Name = "Quincy Tod"],
    [Customer_Name = "Legend Vere"],
    [Customer_Name = "Hendrix Triston"],
    [Customer_Name = "Brycen Hallam"]
}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Customer_Names, "Custom",  each  
let a = Text.Length([Customer_Name]),
b = {0..a-1},
c = Splitter.SplitTextByPositions(b)([Customer_Name]),
d = List.Difference(c, {" "}),
e = List.Sort(List.Transform(d, each Text.Lower(_))),  
f = Text.Combine(e, "")
in f

)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 1):

If pure Excel is an option you can use this formula:

`=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,SORT(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A2)),1),,,TRUE))`

[image]